# Can a php variable contain if statement?

Tags: php

Is it possible for a php variable store an `if` statement?

like this:

```
$num=0;
$var='if($num==0){print "true";}'
```

Comment: Here goes the proverbial... *have you tried it* question.

Comment: Is it possible for you to read a manual?

Comment: No. Variables hold data, `if` statements are code. You seem to have the wrong idea about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I think what he actually meant was is it possible to 'store' an if statement in a variable and 'run' it later on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. But to run `$var` code you need to use `eval` function and it's a very bad practice:

```
<?php
$num=0;
$var='if($num==0){print "true";}';

eval($var);
```

You could consider changing this code into:

```
<?php
$num=0;

$val = 'numFunction';

$val($num);

function numFunction($num)
{
    if($num==0)
        print "true";
}
```

or closure as @Napolux suggested:

```
<?php
$num=0;

$val = function($num)
{
    if($num==0)
        print "true";
};

$val($num);
```

Comment: So bad I would not even write it in an answer :P

Answer (score 1):

You can store a function that runs the if. It's called [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    if($name != '') {
        printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
    }
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
```

Comment: Oh i actually did not know that. :O Thank you i am kinda new myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is

```
$num=0;
if($num==0)
{
$var = true;
print $var;
}
```